# dill.load() from a large file throws EOF error

Tags: python, dill

I'm trying to store a list of histograms for later use, but I'm running into an issue with a very large dataset. I have one set of approximately 100,000 histograms, and I can load that just fine, but when I try to load the second set (containing 500,000~ histograms) it throws an EOF error. Is there some way to avoid this other than breaking up the dataset?

I'm saving the list as such:

```
file = open("file.txt", "w")
dill.dump(test_list, file)
file.close()
```

And I'm loading the list:

```
file = open("file.txt", "r")
test_list = dill.load(file)
file.close()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "image.py", line 263, in <module>
      sys.exit(main())
   File "image.py", line 217, in main
        test_list = dill.load(f)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dill/dill.py", line 288, in load
        obj = pik.load()
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
        dispatch[key](self)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/pickle.py", line 880, in load_eof
        raise EOFError
EOFError
```

Comment: Personally, I'd likely break up the dataset into segments.  If you want something to manage the split and storage for you, you might look at `klepto`, which can use `dill` to store objects into one or multiple files.